# HTML email, navigation to appear at the bottom in mobile

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm learning to code a responsive email template. At the moment here's what I have : https://jsfiddle.net/q12yg2z6/

```
<tr class="main_nav">
    <td id="mobile_nav" width="600">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 15px 20px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #999999;">Nav 1</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 15px 20px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #999999;">Nav 2</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 15px 20px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #999999;">Nav 3</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 15px 20px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #999999;">Nav 4</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 15px 20px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #999999;">Nav 5</a>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 15px 20px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #999999;">Nav 6</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see the top nav on desktop will be stacked at the bottom when it's on mobile. But right now it's appearing in between the main cta and the next two column section. How do I make it appear at the footer. I tried move around with my code but couldn't find the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
@media screen and(max-width:500px){
tr[class="main_nav"] {
   display: table-footer-group;
   position:absolute;
   top:1000px;
   bottom:0px;   
}}
```

Comment: I did your solution but my nav is looking weird after that - https://jsfiddle.net/q12yg2z6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
tr[class="main_nav"] {
    display: table-footer-group;
}
tr[class=main_cta] {
    display: table-header-group;
}
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<tr class="main_nav"></tr>
<tr class="main_cta"></tr>
<tr height="45"></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

Try declaring the other two table rows table-header-group.

Answer (score 0):

h,

The code that's doing stacking in the wrong order is at line 62

```
 tr[class="main_cta"] {
        display: table-header-group;
    }
```

Once that is commented and/or removed the stacking works properly. Once you remove that your navigation gets messed up. It ends up being a small width.

After that do the same to the following:

```
tr[class="main_nav"] {
display: table-footer-group;
```

}

After that it should be fine.

Cheers

Comment: With your suggestion it stacked the menu at the top and that's not what I want. I want it to appear stacked around the footer area

Comment: Hi rory-h, 

You can add width:100%; to the code that Abhishek Pandey has given. It should make it look good. The only thing is you will need to add a few more media queries it seems to get the menu on the right alignment. 

If you have two sets of menus (which i would have done) one for top and one for bottom it will be really good for you to track how users respond to each.

Cheers